# In John 16:13, who is "the spirit of truth"?

Tags: john, pneumatology

I was wondering:
Who is the "Spirit of truth" in this text ?

> John 16
>
> 12 “I have much more to say to you, more than you can now bear.
>
> 13 But when he, the **Spirit of truth**, comes, he will guide you into all
>   the truth. He will not speak on his own; he will speak only what he
>   hears, and he will tell you what is yet to come.
>
> 14 He will glorify me because it is from me that he will receive what
>   he will make known to you.”

Answer (score 2):

Verse 26:

> (NASB) But the Helper, **the Holy Spirit,** whom the Father will send in My name, He will teach you all things, and bring to your remembrance all that I said to you.

---

Jesus Himself speaks of our baptism into His passion and death, so as to be raised with Him (Galatians 3:27; Romans 6:3):

> **Matthew 28:19 (NASB)** Go therefore and make disciples of all the nations, baptizing them in the name of **the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit**

God has a Son, and a Spirit, speaking in human terms. Intricately connected and considered together.

The Holy Spirit is He that proceeds from the Father, God, (as to His generation, or origin as a divine person), and testifies of the Son (John 16:14). He has life from the Father via the Son (again, intimate union), just as the Son Himself lives because of the Father (John 16:15; 6:57).

The same sanctifies us and applies the merits of Christ to us (1 Corinthiains 6:11), convicts the world of its sin (John 16:8).

John the Baptist says, with reference to Jesus, when Jesus was about to begin His ministry and preach the good news of His redemption of mankind that:

> **Matthew 3:11 (NASB)** As for me, I baptize you with water for repentance, but He who is coming after me is mightier than I, and I am not fit to remove His sandals; **He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire.**

When Jesus appeared to his disciples alive again, encouraging them to preach the good news to the whole world, He makes reference to this:

> **Acts 1:4-5 (NASB)** Gathering them together, He commanded them not to leave Jerusalem, but to wait for what the Father had promised, "Which," He said, "you heard of from Me; for John baptized with water, but you will be baptized with the Holy Spirit not many days from now."

Then we read that on the day of Pentecost, 40 days after Christ rose from the dead, the following happened:

> **Acts 1:14-16, 2:22 (NASB)** These all with one mind were continually devoting themselves to prayer, along with the women, and Mary the mother of Jesus, and with His brothers. At this time Peter stood up in the midst of the brethren (a gathering of about one hundred and twenty persons was there together), and said, "Brethren, the Scripture had to be fulfilled, **which the Holy Spirit foretold by the mouth of David** concerning Judas, who became a guide to those who arrested Jesus.

Notice also that the Holy Spirit is the One who inspires the writers of Scripture. The Apostle Peter speaks of Him when he writes: (ASV) For no prophecy ever came by the will of man: but men spake from God, **being moved by the Holy Spirit.**

[image]

> When the day of Pentecost had come, they were all together in one place. And suddenly *there came from heaven a noise like a violent rushing wind, and it filled the whole house where they were sitting. And there appeared to them **tongues as of fire** distributing themselves, and they rested on each one of them.* And they were all **filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak with other tongues,** as the Spirit was giving them utterance. Now there were Jews living in Jerusalem, devout men from every nation under heaven. And when this sound occurred, the crowd came together, and were bewildered because each one of them was hearing them speak in his own language.

Because the Holy Spirit of God is God's Spirit, He is called God:

> **Acts 5:3-4 (NASB)** But Peter said, "Ananias, why has Satan filled your heart to **lie to the Holy Spirit** and to keep back some of the price of the land? "While it remained unsold, did it not remain your own? And after it was sold, was it not under your control? Why is it that you have conceived this deed in your heart? **You have not lied to men but to God."**

Comment: Ok thank you, but who is it ? Who appared later to speak in the name of god after Jesus ?

Comment: Second the 'solia gratia' answer, and especially pointing to the 2 Peter 1 reference 'no prophet ever spoke of his own will...'. The Holy Spirit as the third person in the Trinity seems in the upper room discourse here (Jn 13-17) to be the specified entity in question. As the Son returns to the Father the Spirit empowers and speaks to the disciples so that the written word is preserved and truth given to the church (new testament).

Answer (score 1):

Almost all translations have John 16:13 well translated as something like, "But when he [=that person] the Holy Spirit has come..."  (Eg, NIV, ESV, NRSV, NASB, etc)  The demonstrative pronoun, ekeinos, used here nominative masculine singular and refers back to a more distant antecedent in John 16:6-11, namely the parakletos = advocate, helper, comforter, etc. (See Analytical Lexicon of the New Testament, Friberg, Friberg, Miller; Trafford Publishing, etc)

This grammatical matter at hand is the use of a masculine demonstrative pronoun, ekeinos, with a neuter noun, "the holy Spirit".  This is (I believe) not just John struggling with a foreign language, but a real attempt to drive home the point of the personhood of the Holy Spirit.  (See above reference)

Comment: Can you expand on this comment?

Comment: @Ruminator his answer is based on simple Greek grammar and is common knowledge.  The answer stands on its own.

Comment: Here's a source: "Note ἐκεινος [ekeinos] (masculine demonstrative pronoun, though followed by neuter πνευμα [pneuma] in apposition. See 15:26 for this phrase about the Holy Spirit." (Jn 16:13)

"He (ἐκεινος [ekeinos]). Emphatic masculine pronoun, not neuter (ἐκεινο [ekeino]) though following ὁ [ho]." (Jn 15:26)

Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament. Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>22</sup>Judas saith unto him, not Iscariot, Lord, how is it that thou wilt manifest thyself unto us, and not unto the world?
>   <sup>23</sup>Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him, and **WE will come unto him, and make our abode with him.**
> -- John 14:22-23 (KJV)

The Spirit of Truth is none other than the Father Himself.

> Then said Jesus unto them, When ye have lifted up the Son of man, then shall ye know that I am he, and that I do nothing of myself; **but as my Father hath taught me, I speak these things.**
> -- John 8:28

> **I speak that which I have seen with my Father**: and ye do that which ye have seen with your father.
> -- John 8:38 (KJV>

> <sup>49</sup>For I have not spoken of myself; but **the Father** which sent me, **he gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak.** <sup>50</sup>And I know that his commandment is life everlasting: whatsoever I speak therefore, even as the Father said unto me, so I speak.
> -- John 12:49-50 (KJV)

> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but **the Father that dwelleth in me, he doeth the works.**
> -- John 14:10 (KJV)

> Howbeit when he, **the Spirit of truth**, is come, he will guide you into all truth: for he shall not speak of himself; but **whatsoever he shall hear, that shall he speak**: and he will shew you things to come.
> -- John 16:13 (KJV)

The Father is the Son is the Spirit of Truth.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding (from your two statements) that you only perceive one Person within the Deity ?

Comment: @NigelJ If the Son does nothing of himself and speaks only what the Father has taught him, then he is a conduit through which the Father communicates. Ditto the Holy Spirit. They are both manifestations of the Father -- not separate persons. Jesus said, reiterating Deuteronomy 6:4, "Hear, O Israel; The Lord our God is one Lord:" (Mark 12:29). One means ONE, not three. There would be little profit in pursuing a debate about notions of trinity because the Father's words (delivered via the body of flesh known as Jesus) have settled the issue completely.

Comment: @NigelJ:  If I understand your theology correctly, you subscribe to the doctrine of modalism which asserts that there is one God who simply manifests Himself/Itself in various guises in different situations.  Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan Where on earth did you get that impression from ?

Comment: @NigelJ:  OOPS - my most humble apologies - the comment should have been directed to "enegue".  Please forgive my misrepresentation of you.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan I was beginning to wonder if you had made a mistake with the @ sign. No harm done. No worries.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan I also owe yourself an apology. I have deleted my comment about John. I think I misunderstood you.

Comment: @NigelJ:  No problems and no apology needed here.  I appreciate your comments on this site.  I have much to learn.